# Verify that a type is a coroutine promise_type

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

An empty struct such as: `struct promise_type{};` is not valid as a nested promise_type for the return type of a coroutine. It needs to implement `initial_suspend()` and others.

Is there a way to check that a type is a proper promise_type at compile time with a static_assert similar? I did not find a concept for it.

I would prefer it to fail to compile even if not taken into use yet.

Comment: There are ways to create *traits* that have a static boolean variable that evaluates to `true` if a structure have a specific member, and that the member is a function, and even with a specific signature and return type. This trait can then be used in a `static_assert`. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no concept in the standard for determining the validity of a `promise_type`, but it is not difficult to define such concept using a `requires`-clause that requires the existence of functions with those specific names:

```
template <typename T>
concept coroutine_promise_type = requires(T& t) {
  t.get_return_object();
  t.initial_suspend();
  t.final_suspend();
  t.unhandled_exception();
  // ...
};
```

which can be more stringently constrained by return-type requirements.

Comment: `noexcept(t.final_suspend())` has to be true. Also there must be either 0-param return_void or 1-param return_value - but not both.